# Testing RESTful webservice with kerberos authentication

Tags: soapui, web-service, rest-api

I've been testing a RESTful webservices for the last little while using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).  It's worked great until this week where a requirement was added that the web service must use Kerberos authentication, which SoapUI does not seem to be able to handle.

Although I plan on getting my regression test completely automated using .NET, I still have a little bit more to learn before that becomes a viable option.

I've been spending a little bit of time with [wfetch](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21625) although was hoping that I could find a way to queue up requests or run them in order (I know that I may not be able to have my cake and eat it too).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kerberos authentication can be really, really narky. What I found to solve the "run test as user x in .net" problem I needed to perform a two step process.

Step 1: Fire up the process I want to test as the alternate user.
Step 2: Use impersonation on the call to allow my test harness to access the process from the other user.

This was done for IE in WatiN, but I am guessing that the code will be similar, just calling your chosen test exe.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;


 public static void SetAlternateUser(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        // thread safe singleton code
        lock (threadSafeLock)
        {
            if (_ie == null)
            {
                StartIE();
            }

            _ie.Close();
            _ie = null;


            // fill the NetworkCredeitials object that we use for impersonation
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
            {
                alternateUserCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            }
            else
            {
                alternateUserCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            }

            // Prepare to launch
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.UserName = userName;
            psi.Password = SecurePassword(password);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
            {
                psi.Domain = domain;
            }
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.LoadUserProfile = true;
            psi.FileName = "c:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
            psi.Arguments = "about:blank";


            // launch
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = psi;
            proc.Start();

            // Time to become an imposter
            hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            hTokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (Win32.LogonUser(alternateUserCredentials.UserName, alternateUserCredentials.Domain, alternateUserCredentials.Password, 2 /*LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE*/, 0 /*LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT*/, out hToken))
            {
                if (Win32.DuplicateToken(hToken, 2, out hTokenDuplicate))
                {
                    windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(hTokenDuplicate);
                    impersonationContext = windowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    _ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl("about:blank"));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is "narky" a technical term?  I'm unfamiliar with it. ;-)

Comment: Cool.  This looks helpful.  I probably won't get around to trying it until this weekend though.

Comment: Although I see a lot of potential for it in the future, this doens't seem to help me out as I am attempting to impersonate myself.  the main problem being that IE and soapUI don't seem to authenticate properly.

Comment: Ended up doing some more work with this, and never could get it to work with SoapUI, but I did find that this worked well with a similar tool that we ended up putting together for testing.